# jQuery - click function not firing when content loaded from getjson

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, i'm getting some data back from an API using a getJSON request. I then iterate over the results and populate a table with the data. One on of the 'td's I add a class called 'team' and then have a click function that should simply toggle the background color when this td is clicked. It works when I set up a fiddle and hardcode the td with data. But when its loaded into a table the click function doesnt seem to be firing.

I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PM5Ex/) which shows the basic functionality working fine when the td is hardcoded with some data.

My js for the getJSON is as follows:

```
$.getJSON( "helpers.php", {
})
.done(function( rows ) {
    $.each(rows, function() {
        var row = $('<tr>');
        var teamname = $('<td>').addClass("team").html(this.team);
        var points = $('<td>').html(this.points);
        row.append(teamname, points);
        $('#table-fixtures').append(row);
    });
});
```

and then the JS for the click function:

```
$('td.team').click( function() {    
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

and the CSS, as in the fiddle:

```
.table-fixtures td.team.on {
  background-color: LightGreen;
}
```

So, I cant work out why it works when hardcoded, but not when loaded dynamically. I know the class works as when I add another class as a test it implements the CSS for that class, so its the click functioning not firing, but nothing in the JS console. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `event delegation` in this context,

```
$(document).on('click','td.team',function() {    
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

Please read [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to know more about event delegation.

Comment: wow. quick answer. and it works! thank you. why does this work and not the way I have it set up?

Comment: @m0atz That's because that element not present in the dom while you are registering the events for them.